# Anyone know if there is sheet music for Bud Powell's, "I Can't Get Started"?

Tags: sheet-music

I have looked everywhere on the internet, but cannot seem to find any music for the song, "I Can't Get Started" by Bud Powell. I have loved this song for years, but each time I try to learn it on piano, I can't seem to find any music. I am at an intermediate-high level with the piano so I don't need any simplified version, but the straight-up music. If anyone else is interested in this, the only resource I have been able to find is this Chordify:  [Link](https://chordify.net/chords/bud-powell-songs/i-can-t-get-started-chords)

Thanks!

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://music.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @PiedPiper I interpret the request as for a transcription, not a lead sheet.

Comment: Yes. I have heard Bud Powell play this piece, and I was wondering if there was music for the way he played it.

Comment: There's a lot of Bud Powell transcriptions published, but not that one. However, I Can't Get Started is a standard, and there are other transcriptions available - for example there's a transcription of a Hal Galper version here: http://www.giantsessions.com/jazz-transcriptions-midifiles-mp3/hal-galper/i-cant-get-started

Comment: But more generally, if the song is a standard, there will usually be a bunch of professionally published (as well as self-published) transcriptions for various versions. You might need to do some listening to see how various artists approach the tune, but this is not a bad thing really.